# How Do I Find the Protection on a Given Memory Page?

Tags: macos, memory, memory-management

I am trying to make some memory executable (on Mac OS 10.6), and I suspect that mprotect() is failing silently. Given the address of a page of memory, how can I check that it is in fact marked executable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the memory map of its own process in OS X 10.5/10.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627998/retrieving-the-memory-map-of-its-own-process-in-os-x-10-5-10-6)

Answer (score 1):

Use [vmmap](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/vmmap.1.html) to get output like this:

```
Stack                  00007fff6276e000-00007fff62f6d000 [ 8188K     8K     8K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV          thread 0
Stack                  00007fff62f6d000-00007fff62f6e000 [    4K     4K     4K] rw-/rwx SM=COW          thread 0
__TEXT                 00007fff62f6e000-00007fff62fa3000 [  212K   212K     0K] r-x/rwx SM=COW          /usr/lib/dyld
__DATA                 00007fff62fa3000-00007fff62fa5000 [    8K     8K     8K] rw-/rwx SM=COW          /usr/lib/dyld
__DATA                 00007fff62fa5000-00007fff62fdf000 [  232K    28K    28K] rw-/rwx SM=COW          /usr/lib/dyld
```