# Is it possible to get a "high water mark" of memory usage from Python?

Tags: python, macos, memory-management

Are there any methods in (C)Python to inspect the process' current memory usage? In particular, I'd like to determine the high-water mark of memory usage in a testing script, but if necessary I don't mind periodically checking memory usage and calculating the high water mark for myself.

**EDIT**: I'm looking for either a pure-python solution, or something which works on OS X.

Comment: does calling subprocesses still qualify as 'pure python'?

Comment: that's fine... maybe my question has become, "what OS X command should I call to find out how much memory a particular process is using"? I guess the answer is `ps` or something like it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897941/python-equivalent-of-phps-memory-get-usage/7669279#7669279). It uses the `getrusage()` function from the standard library's `resource` module, and works on Mac OS X.

Comment: Also, this question is _kind of_ a duplicate of the question I linked to, except that question's accepted answer is Linux-only.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you can inspect the `/proc/self/status` file:

```
VmPeak:     6784 kB
VmSize:     6784 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:       572 kB
VmRSS:       572 kB
VmData:      180 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:        44 kB
VmLib:      1640 kB
VmPTE:        36 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
```

Probably `VmPeak` is the line you are most interested in, but if you `mmap(2)` a gigabyte-sized file, you'll probably be accounted for over a gigabyte, even if you only use three or four pages from the file.

If you're aware of the limitations of checking memory via `top(1)` or `ps(1)` then you're probably good to go. If you're not aware of the limitations of checking memory use, then be sure to look into the meanings of the `Virt`, `Res`, and `Shr` columns in `top(1)` output. :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear -- looking for something either pure-Python, or which works on OS X. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `os.getpid()` to get your current PID and then use that PID to find the process in the output of a subprocess calling `top`/`free`/`ps` etc.

i'm not an OSX/BSD expert, so im unsure of the flags to which command will give you memory usage by process

Answer (score 0):

MacosX has `vmmap` and `vmmap64` that you could use to access the information.  I'm not python literate, but I imagine you should be able to open a pipe to a subprocess to read the output somehow.

EDIT: Some additional non-python information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627998/retrieving-the-memory-map-of-its-own-process-in-os-x-10-5-10-6).