# On OS X, how do you find out the current memory protection level?

Tags: c, macos, memory, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieving the memory map of its own process in OS X 10.5/10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627998/retrieving-the-memory-map-of-its-own-process-in-os-x-10-5-10-6)

On OS X, I can use `mprotect()` to request that a specific page of memory be made some combination of readable, writable or executable.

I want to know how to find out what the current protection level is. As an example, on Linux I can `cat /proc/$$/maps` to find out the same information:

```
$ cat /proc/$$/maps
00400000-004db000 r-xp 00000000 fb:00 131145                             /bin/bash
006da000-006db000 r--p 000da000 fb:00 131145                             /bin/bash
006db000-006e4000 rw-p 000db000 fb:00 131145                             /bin/bash
006e4000-006ea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00df4000-00e55000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
...
```

Here I can see that there are 5 ranges of memory mapped for the main executable (`bash`), one is read/execute, one is read-only, and the rest are read/write.

I've looked through all the man pages and official APIs I can find to get the same information on OS X, and have come up empty so far. The only thing I've found that's close is to use `mincore()` to figure out if a page is in-core or not. But that's not enough; I also want the current set of permissions.

Is there any undocumented way to do this?

Comment: @diciu, thanks for the link. Yes, I believe this question is a subset of the question you linked. However, (and I regret not writing this in the question) my next step was going to be to try to get this working on iOS - and the answers there wouldn't apply. Looks like I'd need to explore the "Mach VM region APIs in `/usr/include/mach/mach_vm.h`", as the 2nd most upvoted answer implies. Sadly, the provided link is broken and the header file doesn't exactly make the API obvious.

Comment: For Mac OS X the opened source includes XNU so you should be able to find what you're looking for (http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.24.8/). For iOS, not as much (http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/ios-50/)

Comment: Since virtual memory management is highly architecture dependent, there might not be an API working portably on MacOS X and iOS.

Answer (score 3):

Most VM related system calls can be found in the mach library for OSX.

http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/vm_region.html

Actually most POSIX calls in OSX are just wrappers around the appropriate Mach VM syscalls.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>



int main () {
    void* ptr = malloc(100);

    vm_size_t vmsize;
    vm_address_t address = (vm_address_t)ptr;
    vm_region_basic_info_data_t info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t info_count = VM_REGION_BASIC_INFO_COUNT;
    memory_object_name_t object;

    kern_return_t status =   vm_region(mach_task_self(), &address, &vmsize, VM_REGION_BASIC_INFO,
                           (vm_region_info_t)&info, &info_count, &object);

    if (status) {
        perror("vm_region");
    }

    printf("Memory protection: %c%c%c  %c%c%c\n",
        info.protection & VM_PROT_READ ? 'r' : '-',
        info.protection & VM_PROT_WRITE ? 'w' : '-',
        info.protection & VM_PROT_EXECUTE ? 'x' : '-',

        info.max_protection & VM_PROT_READ ? 'r' : '-',
        info.max_protection & VM_PROT_WRITE ? 'w' : '-',
        info.max_protection & VM_PROT_EXECUTE ? 'x' : '-'
        );

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like those functions are available in `/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib`. Sadly, it doesn't look like there are `man` pages for them. I guess Apple wants you to just use Objective-C and not look at things like this. =)

Comment: Hmm, I can't compile this example code. It says `cannot link directly with /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib. Link against the umbrella framework 'System.framework' instead.` Trying with `-framework System` yields an undefined symbol. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to link fine in 32 bit mode, but fails in 64 bit mode for me. Try with -m32.

Comment: In 64bit mode, you'll want vm_region_64.