# iOS8 , Xcode6 how to get memory usage programmatically as shown by Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcode6, 64-bit

I am using the following to get the memory usage:

```
 struct task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t sizeNew = sizeof(info);
    kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                                   TASK_BASIC_INFO,
                                   (task_info_t)&info,
                                   &sizeNew);
    if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) {
        printf("Memory in use (in bytes): %u", info.resident_size);
    } else {
        printf("Error with task_info(): %s", mach_error_string(kerr));

    }
```

But the memory returned by this is much higher than that of shown by XCode6, any one else facing the same issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Resident set size (RSIZE) is **not** the same as the 'amount of memory used'. it includes the code as well.

You're probably looking for the top equivalent of `RPRVT` from the `top` program.

Obtaining that information requires walking the VM information for the process. Using the [code for libtop.c, function `libtop_update_vm_regions`](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/top/top-100.1.2/libtop.c) as a template, you would need to walk through the entire memory map adding up all the private pages. There's a simpler example of [walking the address space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627998/retrieving-the-memory-map-of-its-own-process-in-os-x-10-5-10-6), which can be used as a basis for calculating this size. You're looking for the `VPRVT` value, *not* the `RPRVT` value.

I don't currently have a mac to hand to write out an example with any degree of confidence that would work.

Comment: Hi , Yes I tried your approach too, but there is also a problem .- 
    task_t task = mach_task_self();
    
    while (true)
    {
        mach_msg_type_number_t count = VM_REGION_TOP_INFO_COUNT;
        myaddr += mysize;
        ret = vm_region_64(mytask, &myaddr, &mysize, VM_REGION_TOP_INFO, (vm_region_info_64_t)&myinfo, &mycount, &myobject_name); 
        if (ret != KERN_SUCCESS)
            break;
        my_private_pages += myinfo.private_pages_resident;
    }
    int pageSize = getpagesize();

Comment: Now if you see vmmemory size it contain pages of size 4K even for 64 bit, where as getMemorySize returns size of 16K .

Comment: Standard pages are 4k for all 32&64bit OSX systems based on the x86 architecture. There are large pages (2mb), but those tend to be allocated in exceptional circumstances. I have no idea about `getMemorySize` or what it does - based on some googling it's a third party function call. `getpagesize()` should be considered the 'right' value. (as mentioned in my answer, my mac is currently in for repairs so this is all based off memory & google; I can't check things directly myself)