# How do you query memory mappings?

Tags: ld, mmap, mprotect

Is there a way to query whether a user memory address range is RO, RW, X, ...?

On BSD, POSIX ... systems *mmap()* and *mprotect()* can be used to set the memory protections of an address range. So there are 'setters' but what is the associated 'getter'?

I ask because a new exploit has surfaced, **CoReV** for Copy Relocation Violation. Basically, *when instantiating a process, constant external variables that are referenced in executables are forcefully relocated to a writable memory segment without warning*.

[An Evil Copy: How the Loader Betrays You](https://nebelwelt.net/publications/files/17NDSS.pdf)

For a constant section, the RO mapping would be 'set' by the loader. But with this exploit, it's necessary to validate the mapping at runtime and that needs a 'getter'.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627998/retrieving-the-memory-map-of-its-own-process-in-os-x-10-5-10-6

Comment: The way I solved this problem was to use DTrace to trace calls to mmap/munmap/mprotect.

Comment: On Linux, look at the file /proc/(processid)/maps